# jQuery UI - dragging somehow ignores overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm making a drag & drop program using jQuery UI:
[Here's the link](http://stvlingen.esy.es/private/testpage/main.html).

[IN CHROME(!) (haven't tested it in other browsers yet)]

So far it's working great, the only thing I have to do is add more content and fix some bugs. One of those bugs really annoys me, because I don't know what to do. In the middle you see a trailer which can be dragged around.
the trailer has two wheels, one at the top and one at the bottom.
When you drag it all the way to the bottom, the page goes up and ignores the overflow. I assume this is because the wheels stick out of the page.

I made those wheels using divs:

```
<section id="product">
    <div class="wheeltop"></div>
    <div class="wheelbottom"></div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
div[class*='wheel']{
    width:20%;
    height:8%;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left:40%;
}

.wheeltop{
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    top:-8%;

}

.wheelbottom{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    bottom:-8%;
}
```

As you see, the blank space which appears at the bottom of the screen has the same height as each 'wheel'.

I passed `overflow:hidden` to the `body`.

Perhaps there is a way to force the page to always stick to it's position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `overflow-y` to `hidden` on `#mainContainer` it should prevent the white space from appearing at the bottom.

This works in Chrome (v.49.0.2623.39), FireFox (v.44) and Edge (v.25.10586.0.0).

Comment: Haha, you again! Anyways thanks for the help, can't believe I haven't figured this out earlier.

Comment: A happy coincidence :) No probs!